# Ionic 2: avatar wrong shape

Tags: css, ionic2

Why is my avatar image rendering like this? I'm just assigning a photo to the standard markup from the Ionic docs V2 e.g.:

```
<ion-menu id="leftMenu" [content]="content" side="left">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-item class="menu-header">
      <ion-avatar item-left class="menu-avatar">
          <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>Joe Bloggs</h2>
    </ion-item>    
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="home" item-left></ion-icon>Home
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="home" item-left></ion-icon>Home
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="home" item-left></ion-icon>Home
      </ion-item>      
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage" #content swipe-back-enabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Here's a plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/EGDhKzSyaI3WZugldn4W?p=preview

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you create a plunker with that code? That way would be easier to find out what's going on there...

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/EGDhKzSyaI3WZugldn4W?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the size of the image (should be a square like `45px x 45px` or `300px x 300px`)

If you change your image for this one, you can see the avatar is rendered properly:

```
<img src="https://www.placecage.com/300/300">
```

If you still want to use a image that is not a square, if you add this in your page styles that issue should be fixed:

```
ion-avatar img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: hey again, yeah I figured that might work, but it skews the aspect ratio.  What would be better is if there's a way to centre the image instead of warping it.

Comment: i tried `ion-avatar` i am getting like same image as question here is my inspect element goes `.item-ios ion-avatar img {
    max-width: 3.6rem;
    max-height: 3.6rem;
    border-radius: 1.8rem;
}`

Comment: i tried to css as you did but no use I am trying to implement the ion-avatar insted of ion-thumbnal given by the ionic team but i am getting the circled image